# Make animation smooth while recognizing QRCode with ZBar

Tags: android, animation, camera

I have use [ZBarSDK](https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner) for recognizing QRCode.I'm trying to add an Scanner Overlay to the CameraPreview.In the Scanner Overlay,I'm trying add an animation for the scanner.But the animation is very slow.
Here is my animation code:

```
scanLine.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Logger.i(CameraOverlay.class, "addOnGlobalLayoutListener");
            scanLine.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            scanLine.clearAnimation();
            scanLine.setAnimation(null);
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, scanRect.width() - 10, 0, 0);
            animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
            animation.setDuration(2600);
            scanLine.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I found `Camera.setPreviewCallback` is too expensive.Then I use `Camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback` instead.